# Automating testing for a MFC class

Tags: c++, testing, mfc

I have a MFC class here and im trying to create an automated test for it. I have the added conveniance of never having done MFC before s othats great. Anyway, Im just wondering what would be ways to do it without having to worry too much about a GUI.

Its gonna be a simple gui. Just a start button and a stop button. When start is hit, the test will send a load of packets (not really packets but lets call them that for simplicity sake) to the class that is being tested. This Class will process the packets. The test will end when the stop button is hit.

One guy said to make the GUI invisible and then just use timers to send a start event, then run the test then use a timer to send a stop event. Is that feasible?

Have people tried other ways or know of other approaches?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can first do unit testing ([cppunit](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppunit/index.php?title=Main_Page)) to ensure that the nuts and bolts work. How about [Quick Test Profession as it was use to be called](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Quality_Center). Alternative look into this [list]. One of these may be cheaper[3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools)